# C++ weird instantiation of struct

Tags: c++

I have a struct in a header file as shown here

```
struct GraphNode {
        Id id {};
        std::string name {};
        long long int passengerCount {0};
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>> edges {};

        // Find the edge for a specific line route.
        std::vector<
            std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>
        >::const_iterator FindEdgeForRoute(
            const std::shared_ptr<RouteInternal>& route
        ) const;
    };
```

I'm not sure about the "find the edge for a specific line route" part of the code. So is `FindEdgeForRoute` a vector of shared pointers to type `GraphEdge`, but instead of a normal vector it's an iterator? I'm confused.

It's also instantiated in this particular manner:

```
bool TransportNetwork::AddStation(
    const Station& station
)
{
    // Create a new station node and add it to the map.
    auto node {std::make_shared<GraphNode>(GraphNode {
        station.id,
        station.name,
        0, // We start with no passengers.
        {} // We start with no edges.
    })};
    return true;
}
```

Is the above the same as if I do

```
bool TransportNetwork::AddStation(
    const Station& station
)
{
        GraphNode node;          
        node.id = station.id;
        node.name = station.name;
        node.passengerNumber = 0;
}
```

And I don't know how I would initialize the `FindEdgeForRoute` function. Can anyone help clarify this?

Comment: It's not very good code. But still, what an iterator is, and what a constructor does should be covered in your C++ text book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is FindEdgeForRoute a vector of shared pointers to type GraphEdge, but instead of a normal vector it's an iterator?

What you see in the `struct` definition is that it declares a `const` *member function* called `FindEdgeForRoute` that takes one parameter (a `const std::shared_ptr<RouteInternal>&`) and returns a `const_iterator` into a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>>`.

> I don't know how I would initialize the FindEdgeForRoute function.

You need to call it with a `std::shared_ptr<RouteInternal>`.

Comment: Thus I can say that each of std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>in the vector are const_iterators?

Comment: @aido no, the iterators are more like pointers into the vector. Your vector itself does not store iterators, it stores `std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>>` objects

Comment: Ah so it points to each of std::shared_ptr<GraphEdge>> in the vector?

Comment: @aldo Yes! The iterator may in fact be just that, a plain pointer.

Comment: I tried to initialize FindEdgeForRoute with: ```const std::shared_ptr<RouteInternal> test;
        node.FindEdgeForRoute(test);``` but it didn't work. Perhaps you know why?

Comment: @aldo It's hard to say without more context. Perhaps you can open a new question and provide a [mre] so that we can see the bigger picture?